# How to use GCM in iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

Not good at English

I need to make push notification in iOS with GCM
so I'm following https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift

1. but I don't know how can i get the notification by GCM.
   When I test it use 'GcmServerDemo' that can get in pod try Google
   sometimes work but not always.
   Is there any good example or tutorial?
2. In console shows token like 'nWYjGeTAqlU:APA91bFiqDjQoK6Adg3OStJPYLD2JK-ZW2XMTY2XQKF0SWWQ2vCszeMxPbrB08PyTNdfhQI9YtMopJpdzgHRtJueaDH7xj79OMYYKq_zqM_uraC68w7bOM0mlFXxPjwEvicGhmv3qZdd'
   token is after nWYjGeTAqlU: or full string?

Comment: Have you generate a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file by uploading your APNS  P12 file to the [GCM portal](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fios%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue)? If not, you need to make one before you using the GCM demo.

Answer (score 0):

The token is the entire string. Once you've registered your app with GCM and have a registration token you can use a simple `cURL` request to see if it all works.

```
curl -v --data-ascii '{"notification":{ "body":"Test '"$(date)"'"}, "to":$regToken}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:key=$authKey" https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Substitute `$regToken` with your registration token and `$authKey` with your Authorization key from the Dev console. If you've successfully registered and everything is fine you should get a notification on your device.